# Flutter go_router 5 How to maintain state and preload the pages?

Tags: flutter, go, router, flutter-go-router

I would like to maintain the state of screen (for exemple if i scroll down in a tab and change the tab and come back it is scrolled down). Aswell I wold like to preload all the the screens on start so when i change the tab in the bottom bar go fast and dosen't load it again.

I got his behaviour with IndexedStack and Navigator.
Is it possible  with go_route 5? how?

Thanks

Comment: this is an open issue on `go_router`. You can check this link to get updates on this:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99124